# How to use Radio Buttons that effect Check boxes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, radio-button, visual-studio-2017

Hello I was wondering if anyone could help to tell me what I am doing wrong. So for my assignment I need to make it so that whenever you select a specific radio button on the left side of my form it changes the available options for add on items on the right side of my form. For my assignment it says to make one event handler to do this. Here is the exact line from the assignment

"Code an event handler that changes the text that’s displayed for the Add-ons group box and the three check boxes when the user selects a different main course. This event handler should also remove the check marks from the add-ons and clear the order totals. Test the application to be sure this works correctly."

I cannot figure out why my code won't work. I have tried a few different things now. Any help would be very appreciated. Here is a screenshot of the form for reference and my code underneath that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIcHE.jpg

```
    Private Sub ClearTexts()
    txtOrderTotal.Text = ""
    txtSubTotal.Text = ""
    txtTax.Text = ""
End Sub
Private Sub ClearChecks()
    chbBox1.Checked = False
    chbBox2.Checked = False
    chbBox3.Checked = False
End Sub


Private Sub grpAddon_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grpAddon.TextChanged

    If rbHamburger.Checked Then
        chbBox1.Text = "Lettuce, tomato, and onions"
        chbBox2.Text = "Ketchup, mustard, and mayo"
        chbBox3.Text = "French fries"
    ElseIf rbPizza.Checked Then
        chbBox1.Text = "Pepperoni"
        chbBox2.Text = "Sausage"
        chbBox3.Text = "Olives"
    ElseIf rbSalad.Checked Then
        chbBox1.Text = "Croutons"
        chbBox2.Text = "Bacon Bits"
        chbBox3.Text = "Bread Sticks"
    End If

    ClearTexts()
    ClearChecks()
End Sub
```

Comment: Watch [(VB.NET Tutorial 2 : How to use Groupbox , RadioButtons and CheckBoxes in Visual Basic .NET](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlwaGKzmJnM)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are targeting the wrong Event.  Your subroutine should handle the `CheckedChanged` events of the RadioButtons and not the `TextChanged` event of the GroupBox.

```
Private Sub grpAddon_RadioChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbHamburger.CheckedChanged, rbPizza.CheckedChanged, rbSalad.CheckedChanged

    chbBox1.Checked = False
    chbBox2.Checked = False
    chbBox3.Checked = False

    If rbHamburger.Checked Then
        chbBox1.Text = "Lettuce, tomato, and onions"
        chbBox2.Text = "Ketchup, mustard, and mayo"
        chbBox3.Text = "French fries"
    ElseIf rbPizza.Checked Then
        chbBox1.Text = "Pepperoni"
        chbBox2.Text = "Sausage"
        chbBox3.Text = "Olives"
    ElseIf rbSalad.Checked Then
        chbBox1.Text = "Croutons"
        chbBox2.Text = "Bacon Bits"
        chbBox3.Text = "Bread Sticks"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You're the man! That explanation actually makes a lot of sense too! Thanks so much!